# Does org.joda.time.Period respect leap years?

Tags: java, date, jodatime

I am doing some unit testing and have happened across this:

2015 (Not a Leap Year)

```
LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.parse("01/03/2015", new DateTimeFormatterFactory("dd/MM/yyyy").createDateTimeFormatter());
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse("25/02/2015", new DateTimeFormatterFactory("dd/MM/yyyy").createDateTimeFormatter());

org.joda.time.Period.fieldDifference(startDate, endDate).getDays(); // is -24
```

2016 (Leap Year)

```
LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.parse("01/03/2016", new DateTimeFormatterFactory("dd/MM/yyyy").createDateTimeFormatter());
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse("25/02/2016", new DateTimeFormatterFactory("dd/MM/yyyy").createDateTimeFormatter());

org.joda.time.Period.fieldDifference(startDate, endDate).getDays(); // is ALSO -24
```

I would expect these values to be at least different.

Any ideas?

Comment: Oops. That was a typo in the sample, I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The doc for [`fieldDifference`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html#fieldDifference-org.joda.time.ReadablePartial-org.joda.time.ReadablePartial-) says

> Calculation by field difference works by extracting the difference
>   one field at a time and not wrapping into other fields.
>   Thus 2005-06-09/2007-04-12 will yield P1Y-2M3D.

The difference in the *day field* between "01/03/2016" and "25/02/2016" is `1 - 25 = -24`. It is not saying that is the number of days between the two dates. `-24` would not make sense as the number of days between those two dates in any year.

To find the number of days between two dates, you could use

```
org.joda.time.Days.daysBetween(startDate, endDate).getDays()
```

which will indeed return a different number in 2015 from 2016 if it crosses the end of February.

Comment: I understood this to be (some month minus 24 days). But shouldn't it be different for a leap year? org.joda.time.Period.fieldDifference(startDate, endDate).getMonths(); is 1, in both cases. getDays() is -24, in both cases.

Comment: Also, it is not about what I want, I am stuck with "Period.fieldDifference". I just want to know why it returns the same number of days for leap and non-leap years.

Comment: `fieldDifference` just tells you the difference between the two fields. The difference between `25` and `1` is `-24`. That is what it is telling you. If you want something else, use a different method.

Comment: OK, I get it now, thanks. Your last comment is the answer I was seeking. I didn't really understand the docs "one field at a time and not wrapping into other fields", Now, with your (1-25) illustration, everything is aligned.